# How to use bottom navigator 'OnTap' in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an app where i have a list(for eg news).And in the bottom toolbar i have a previous and next button.what i want to do is if i am on **third news and i clicked on the previous button it should go on second news.**I have made the toolbar and will attach the code below.I have added full code for better understanding.Thank you.

```
class Newsdetail extends StatefulWidget {
 String  value_image, value_description, value_title;
  int index;


  Newsdetail(
      {Key key,
      @required this.value_image,
      this.value_description,
      this.value_title,
      this.index})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _newsdetail createState() => _newsdetail();
}

class _newsdetail extends State<Newsdetail> {
  int _currentindex=0;
  _newsdetail();
  var tabs =[];

    loadyourNews() async {


setState(() {

  tabs = [
  Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 10.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child:
                Image.network(widget.value_image))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Image.asset('images/facebook.png',),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _openFacebook();
                          }),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('images/twitter.png',),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _openTwitter();
                        },
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset(
                          'images/whatsappicon.png', width: 180.0,
                          height: 180.0,),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _openWhatsapp();
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    widget.value_title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),


              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      widget.value_description,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
];
});

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadyourNews();
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF125688),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,5.0,0),
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 30,
                child: FlatButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    onPressed: (){},
                    child: Text('A+',style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22.0,color: Colors.white
                    ),))),
          ),

          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,38.0,0),
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 30,
                child:FlatButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  onPressed: (){},
                  child: Text('A-',style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,color: Colors.white
                  ),),

                )),
          )

        ],
      ),
      body: tabs[_currentindex],

      bottomNavigationBar:BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentindex,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF125688),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            title: Text('Previous',style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white
            ),),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,

          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            title: Text('Next',style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white
            ),),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,

          ),
        ],
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            if (index == 0) {
              _currentindex = (_currentindex - 1) % tabs.length;
              if (_currentindex < 0) _currentindex += _currentindex;
            } else
              _currentindex = (_currentindex + 1) % tabs.length;
          });

        },
      ),

    );
  }
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to create from scratch a functionality that already exists in Flutter. A widget called [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html).

Comment: @JoãoSoares I want to call it on click of the button.

Comment: And you can do exactly that with a PageController.

Comment: BottomNavigationBar is not used for this purpose. You should check `BottomAppBar` instead.

Comment: @MidhunMP could you show me any example of how could i achieve my results using 'BottomAppBar'

Answer (score 0):

Use Navigator.push and Navigator.pop for next and previous button respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you want to do with a `PageView`:

```
class PageViewScaffoldIssue extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageViewScaffoldIssueState createState() => _PageViewScaffoldIssueState();
}

class _PageViewScaffoldIssueState extends State<PageViewScaffoldIssue> {
  PageController _pageController = PageController();
  List<String> _stringList = [
    'Page 1',
    'Page 2',
    'Page 3',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            children: _stringList.map((item) => NewsArticle(article: item,)).toList(),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () => _pageController.previousPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), curve: Curves.easeInOut),
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              label: Text('Previous'),
            ),
            RaisedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () => addArticle(),
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              label: Text('Add'),
            ),
            RaisedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () => _pageController.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), curve: Curves.easeInOut),
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
              label: Text('Next'),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void addArticle(){
    setState(() {
      _stringList.add('Page ${_stringList.length+1}');
    });
  }
}

class NewsArticle extends StatelessWidget {
  final String article;

  NewsArticle({
    @required this.article,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(this.article),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.As it is the news app number of news coming everyday varies.So how could i tackle this issue using your anwser?

Comment: You just need to have your News be a List of Widgets and feed that List to the PageView, whenever there are new or changed News, you use setState to make sure it gets rebuilt.

Comment: I have just started flutter and wont be able to execute what you are saying..can you pls edit your answer accordingly.Thanks

Comment: I've made the list of articles a variable and added a method that adds more articles to the list and uses `setState` to make sure it gets rebuilt. If you click the `Add` button and then the `Next` button, you will see that new pages get added and you keep going through them. From this code you should be able to build the rest of what you need.

Comment: I cannot add "Add" button in the app..I have posted my android code above to achieve this result.

Comment: You don't have to add the "Add" button. It was just an example from which you can build on. I will not be writing the code for you. I am also not sure why you are sharing your Android code.